# Multi-Part upload has no payload

Tags: file-upload, electron, multipartform-data, chromium

I am trying to do a multi-part upload from my javascript application and it works fine in the chrome browser but fails without error when run in electron.
I can't find information, why it fails in electron, but maybe some of you have an idea? :)

```
var fileContent = new Uint8Array([64,65,66,67]);
var fileBlob = new Blob([fileContent], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});  
var data = new FormData();
data.set('file', fileBlob, 'blob.bin');  
fetch('http://my.end.point', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
});
```

When I run that code in Chrome, I can see the 4 bytes payload in the network tab and my end point receives the 4 bytes. If I do the same in electron, the payload in the network tab is empty and the end point receives the multi-part request with the payload missing. I also tried using XMLHttpRequest instead of fetch but that shows exactly the same behavior.

Request Payload from within electron:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryNXzPiiAvBttdDATr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob.bin"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryNXzPiiAvBttdDATr--
```

Request payload from withon chrome browser:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarywTEtXn4z3NFt3sAb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob.bin"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

@ABC
------WebKitFormBoundarywTEtXn4z3NFt3sAb--
```

Does someone know, why it doesn't work from within electron?

Comment: After checking different older chromium versions it seems it was a chromium bug and is fixed with version 66.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I didn't know that I had to wrap my `buffer` in a blob `new Blob([buffer], { type: 'image/png' })` before uploading. This fixed my problem.